# fill combobox from mysql data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have 3 combobox, see the following code

```html
<select name="option1" id="option1" onchange="populate(this.id,'option2','option3','option4')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">public</option>
    <option value="2">private</option>
</select><br>     
<select name="option2" id="option2" onchange="populate('option1',this.id,'option3','option4')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">primary</option>
    <option value="2">secondary</option>
</select><br>    
<select name="option3" id="option3" onchange="populate('option1','option2',this.id,'option4')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">office1</option>
    <option value="2">office2</option>
    <option value="3">office3</option>
    <option value="4">office4</option>
</select><br>
```

I need get values from mysql table with parameter from the first 3 combobox, to fill the last combobox. So this is my sql query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `schools` WHERE `kind_of_education` LIKE '.$option1.' `AND `class_type` LIKE '.$option2.' AND `office` LIKE '.$option3.";`
```

I want do that like this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function populate(s1,s2){
 var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
 var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
 s2.innerHTML = "";
 if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
  var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
 } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
  var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
 } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
  var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  s2.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code beatifying for flexible reading

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your $sql variable in php to call your database, and then instead of listing flat options make a foreach loop on the results of your query to fill the values of your options

Answer (score 0):

i was try this code, but it have many truble :

```html
<script>
            function populate(op1,op2,op3,op4){
                    var op1 = document.getElementById(op1).value.toString();
                    var op2 = document.getElementById(op2).value.toString();
                    var op3 = document.getElementById(op3).value.toString();
                    var op4 = document.getElementById(op4).value.toString();
                    op4.innerHTML = "";
                       <?php
                         $op1="<script>op1.value.toString();</script>";
                         $op2="<script>op2</script>";
                         $op3="<script>op3</script>";
                         
                         $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','yaser95','123456789');

                         mysql_select_db('students',$conn);

                         $query = "SELECT `school_id`, `school_name` FROM `schools` WHERE `kind_of_education`=$op1 and `class_type`=1 and `office`=1 ORDER BY `school_name`";

                         $sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
                         $result = mysql_query($sSQL,$conn)  or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');

                         $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
                         $selectbox='<select name=\'schools\'>';

                         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             "<script>
                             var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                             newOption.value =" $row['school_id']
                             "newOption.innerHTML =" $row['school_name']
                             "s2.options.add(newOption);
                           </script>"  
                          }
                       ?>    
            }
        </script>
```